# File upload with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, file-upload, sinatra, paperclip

I am trying to be able to upload files with Sinatra. I have the code [here](http://github.com/eturk/marvin), but I'm getting the error "method file_hash does not exist" (see /lib/mvc/helpers/helpers.rb).

What is going on here? Is there some dependency I'm missing.

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to use paperclip with this. Could you paste your code again (link leads to a dead page)? Otherwise, what was your solution?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I've had good luck with the example code found on [this thread](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/193036).

Including it here in case the link ever disappears:

```
post '/upload' do
  unless params[:file] &&
         (tmpfile = params[:file][:tempfile]) &&
         (name = params[:file][:filename])
    @error = "No file selected"
    return haml(:upload)
  end
  STDERR.puts "Uploading file, original name #{name.inspect}"
  while blk = tmpfile.read(65536)
    # here you would write it to its final location
    STDERR.puts blk.inspect
  end
  "Upload complete"
end
```

Then your view would look like this. This uses HAML, but the important part is not to forget to set the enctype in your form element, otherwise you will just get the filename instead of an object:

```
%form{:action=>"/upload",:method=>"post"   ,:enctype=>"multipart/form-data"}
  %input{:type=>"file",:name=>"file"}
  %input{:type=>"submit",:value=>"Upload"}
```

Comment: that seems to dump it to the console

Answer (score 26):

```
include FileUtils::Verbose

get '/upload' do
    erb :upload
end

post '/upload' do
    tempfile = params[:file][:tempfile] 
    filename = params[:file][:filename] 
    cp(tempfile.path, "public/uploads/#{filename}")
    'Yeaaup'
end

__END__

@@upload
<form action='/upload' enctype="multipart/form-data" method='POST'>
    <input name="file" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

I found, slightly changed and used this:

```
if params[:file]
  filename = params[:file][:filename]
  tempfile = params[:file][:tempfile]
  target = "public/files/#{filename}"

  File.open(target, 'wb') {|f| f.write tempfile.read }
end
```

The original is at https://github.com/tbuehlmann/sinatra-fileupload but have some config issues at my environment. Don't forget to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and `method="POST"` at the upload form.

Comment: In my situation, I find that the first hash key is a string - not a symbol - eg. `params['file']`

Comment: Fix line: target = "public/files/#{filename}"