# Handling a file upload within the padrino framework

Tags: ruby, file-upload, sinatra, padrino

I am building a small file upload service using the Sinatra framework with Padrino. I am pretty new to the whole world of html, php, rails style development, all of it. When using just a [file_field_tag](http://www.padrinorb.com/guides/application-helpers#form-helpers), I can generate a generic html file field tag, but as my bible [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) says, the tag merely generates a link to the file, and I need to make a ASP, PHP file to handle the actual upload of the file.

So what's going on here? Do I need to create my own php action command that lives outside of my framework? That seems like the wrong solution. I would rather have padrino handle the actual upload of files. When I did bite the bullet, I wrote a tiny php script, but my padrino form filler treats "myaction.php" as a post page, when I just wanna run my php script.

Comment: No, there's no PHP involved here.  There's no reason that Sinatra can't handle a file upload.  Also, you should stop paying attention to anything w3schools tells you, they're *horrible*.  Use https://developer.mozilla.org/ instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686044/file-upload-with-sinatra