# ruby, sinatra, padrino,slim

Tags: ruby, sinatra, padrino, slim-lang

I need to develop a simple File Upload 
I'm using padrino and *slim-templates*. Also generated my views using the padrino command generator such as `padrino g admin_pages modelName`. Now I want to add a `fileUpload` field to the generated code... I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

My question is any way to automatically generate the admin page with this functionality or simply add the field manualy?

This is the code:

```
= f.text_field :newName, :class => 'form-control input-large input-with-feedback',    
= f.label :content, :class => 'control-label'
= f.text_area :content, :class => 'form-control input-large input-with-feedback'
= f.file_field  :fileimg    
= f.submit pat(:save), :multipart => true ,:class => 'btn btn-primary'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which line you get the error in?

Comment: the error appears when y put the line "= f.file_field  :fileimg  "... actually fileimg it's an attribute from the model that i want to create, if i change fileimg for "imgVariable"(that not belongs to the model) i have other error...

Comment: it seems that `fileimg` field is `nil` for the record `f`

Comment: Solved using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686044/file-upload-with-sinatra
And 
http://alfuken.tumblr.com/post/874428235/upload-and-download-files-in-sinatra
Thanks!

Comment: was it really `nil` `fileimg` ?

Comment: or it was problem in another part of code? it another specify the answer

Comment: Yes it was nil
what i did to solve this was:
1) Enter the fileimg in the model that i'm working in this case.
2) In the form i changed a little to this  = f.file_field :fileimg, :name =>'file'

So in i controller i capture the file
this way params[:file][:tempfile]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that *`fileimg`* field is `nil` for the record `f`. Make sure that it isn't `nil, and in that case, it shell be validated by a model validation rule.